# Expected value of Brownian motion at a time decided by a rate one Poisson process.

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times, poisson-process, expected-value

**Situation:**

> We have that $\{W_{t},t\geq 0\}$ is a Brownian motion and
>   $\{N_{t},t\geq 0\}$ is a Poisson process such that $N_{t}$ follows a
>   Poisson distribution with parameter $t$. This process is independent
>   from our Brownian motion.

**Question:** a) Show that $\mathbb{E}[W^{2}_{N_{t}}]=t$

b) For $a\geq 0$ we define the stopping time: $\tau=\inf\{t\geq 0:|W_{t}|>a\}$. Show that this stopping time is finite.

**My attempt:** a) Keeping in mind that Brownian motion has independent normally distributed increments, I rewrite the problem into:

$\mathbb{E}[W^{2}_{N_{t}}]=\mathbb{E}[(W_{N_{t}}-W_{s}+W_{s})^{2}]$ where $0\leq s<N_{t}$.

Using the Brownian motion properties a few more times, this reduces to $\mathbb{E}[W^{2}_{N_{t}}]=N_{t}$, which looks like the desired answer but obviously is not. I thought of doing the same trick but with $N_{s}$ instead of $s$, but again no luck. This is a trick I learned during lectures but I'm starting to doubt if it works here aswell.

b) Intuitively, this makes obvious sense. Eventually we will cross hit $a$ and thus the stopping is finite. However, I struggle to make this a solid proof. Perhaps I could use the Law of Large Numbers but I'm not sure if it is applicable here.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $N_t$ is a random variable and therefore the statement "where $0 \leq s < N_t$" doesn't make sense.

---

$N_t$ takes values in $\mathbb{N}_0$ and because of the independence from $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ we have

$$\mathbb{E}(W_{N_t}^2) = \mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{k \geq 0} W_k^2 1_{\{N_t = k\}} \right) = \sum_{k \geq 0} \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(W_k^2)}_{=k} \underbrace{\mathbb{P}(N_t=k)}_{=e^{-t} t^k/k!} = t e^{-t} \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} =t.$$

Alternatively, we can use the tower property of the conditional expectation to show that

$$\mathbb{E}(W_{N_t}^2) = \mathbb{E} \big[ \mathbb{E}(W_{N_t}^2 \mid N_t) \big] = \mathbb{E} \big[ \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(W_k^2)}_{=k} \big|_{k=N_t} \big] = \mathbb{E}(N_t)=t.$$

---

To prove that the stopping time $\tau$ is almost surely finite we can use the optional stopping theorem. Since $M_t := W_t^2-t$ is a martingale, it follows from the optional stopping theorem that $$\mathbb{E}(W_{t \wedge \tau}^2) = \mathbb{E}(t \wedge \tau).$$ Since $|W_{t \wedge \tau}| \leq a$ this gives $$\mathbb{E}(t \wedge \tau) \leq a^2,$$ and now the monotone convergence theorem yields $$\mathbb{E}(\tau) \leq a^2$$ which shows, in particular, that $\tau<\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Thanks alot, once again. Your solution for a) using the tower property makes perfect sense. I have a question about your solution for b), though. How do you conclude from $|W_{t \wedge \tau}| \leq a$ that $\mathbb{E}(t \wedge \tau) \leq a$? I'm struggling to relate the fact that  $|W_{t \wedge \tau}| \leq a$ to $\mathbb{E}(W_{t \wedge \tau}^2)$.

Comment: @S.Crim If $X$ is a random variable such that $0 \leq X \leq b$, then $\mathbb{E}(X) \leq b$, right? That's what I used to estimate $\mathbb{E}(W_{t \wedge \tau}^2)$. (Sorry, there was a square missing in my estimate; should be fine now... perhaps this was the reason for your confusion.)

Comment: Shouldn't it be that $\mathbb{E}(W_{t \wedge \tau}^2) \leq a^{2}$ then? Ah, you editted it haha! I get it now, thanks alot.

Comment: @S.Crim Yeah, sorry for the typo.

Comment: I just came back to this question after attempting to solve it again and I ran into a problem. How exactly can you say that $|W_{t \wedge \tau}| \leq a$? Isn't it, because of the way our stopping time is defined, that in the case that $t \wedge \tau = \tau$ that we have that $|W_{\tau}|>a$? Which would mean that in that case the inequality you gave does not hold?

Comment: @S.Crim It follows from the continuity of the sample paths that $|W_{\tau}| = a$; moreover, the very definition of the stopping time gives $|W_{s}(\omega)| \leq a$ for any $s<\tau(\omega)$ and so $|W_{t \wedge \tau}(\omega)| \leq a$.

Comment: Perhaps I am too inexperienced but it does not make sense to me that $|W_{\tau}| = a$ when we say that $\tau=\inf\{t\geq 0:|W_{t}|>a\}$ which says that we stop the process when we cross over $a$, right? I understand the continuity and that we couldn't ''jump'' over $a$, but still we must be larger than $a$ when we stop, right?

Comment: @S.Crim No, it's not larger than $a$. If $|W_{\tau}(\omega)|$ was strictly larger than $a$, then by the intermediate value theorem theoerem there would exist $s < \tau(\omega)$ such that $a<|W_s(\omega)| < |W_{\tau}(\omega)|$ which is a contradiction to the very definition of the stopping time $\tau$.

Comment: So basically $\tau=\inf\{t\geq 0:|W_{t}|>a\}$ is the same as $\tau=\inf\{t\geq 0:|W_{t}|=a\}$? As in, it makes no difference as to which of the 2 definitions for $\tau$ you use? If they're not the same, then what is the difference?

Comment: @S.Crim Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Alright I'll have to look into that a bit more then. Thanks again for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Any chance we can talk in the chat like the site suggests? I have notes from my teacher specifically saying that $\inf\{t\geq 0:|W_{t}|>a\}\neq \inf\{t\geq 0:|W_{t}|=a\}$, which makes sense. I can't get behind the reason why they'd be equal.

Comment: @S.Crim Ah, sorry, I misread what you wrote. So the stopping times are indeed not equal, but nevertheless it holds that $|W_{\tau}|=a$ ...as I already explained in an earlier comment, you can use the intermediate value theorem to prove this.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again with such an old question, but something is unclear to me once again. How exactly do we conclude this $$\mathbb{E}(W_{N_t}^2) = \mathbb{E} \big[ \mathbb{E}(W_{N_t}^2 \mid N_t) \big] = \mathbb{E} \big[ \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(W_k^2)}_{=k} \big|_{k=N_t} \big] = \mathbb{E}(N_t)=t$$? I understand the tower property, but how come we have that $\mathbb{E}[W^2_t|N_t]=N_t$?

Comment: @S.Crim The thing which you need to understand is that $$\mathbb{E}(W_{N_t}^2 \mid N_t) = \mathbb{E}(W_k^2) \bigg|_{k=N_t}$$ ... this identity is a consequence of known properties of the conditional expectation and the independence of $(W_t)$ and $(N_t)$.

Comment: So this basically says that the expectation of $W_t^2$, given that we know the value of $t$, i.e. we condition on $t$, is equal to $t$? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: @S.Crim You can hardly condition on something deterministic, can you? It all relies on the fact that $$\mathbb{E}(h(X,Y) \mid X) = \mathbb{E}(h(x,Y)) \big|_{x=X}$$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

Comment: Thing is, I'm probably asking stupid questions because during my lessons I have never seen this notation $\mathbb{E}(W_k^2) \bigg|_{k=N_t}$, i.e. with the conditioning line outside of the expectation. Is there another way of writing it?

Comment: @S.Crim $f(N_t)$ where $f(k) := \mathbb{E}(W_k^2)$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I have a quick question about this step where you use the monotone convergence theorem. We can only use the monotone convergence theorem if $\tau \wedge t \uparrow \tau$, right? But we can only say that if we already know that $\tau$ is a finite stopping time, right? So aren't you using the very thing you want to prove?

Comment: @S.Crim $\min\{t,\tau\} \uparrow \tau$ holds also on $\{\tau=\infty\}$; just note that $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \min\{t,\tau(\omega)\} = \infty = \tau(\omega)$$ for all $\omega \in \{\tau=\infty\}$.

Comment: Ah, I find that kinda hard to grasp. Because then we also have that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \min\{t,\tau(\omega)\} = \infty = \tau(\omega)=t$, right? Since $t$ is going to infinity aswell.

Comment: @S.Crim Not sure whether it's just a typo... we have $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \min\{t,\tau(\omega)\} = \lim_{t \to \infty} t = \infty = \tau(\omega)$$ on $\{\tau=\infty\}$. (You wrote $\tau(\omega)=t$; that's wrong, note that this equation doesn't even make sense here)

Comment: Oh god, you're right lol, apologies for that. Reading back my comment I'm not sure what I was even asking. Thanks alot anyway.

Comment: But let's say that we have that $\tau(\omega)=\infty$, is $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ even ''defined'' in that case? I'm asking because I'm looking at the definition of the MCT in terms of measurable functions. Where, if our stopping time would be infinite, we would integrate over infinity, right? Is that just equal to infinity?

Comment: @S.Crim If a stopping time $\tau$ takes the value $+\infty$ with positive probability, then $\mathbb{E}(\tau)=\infty$. However, in our case here we have shown that $\mathbb{E}(\tau)<\infty$ and hence $\tau<\infty$ almost surely